# Git Fugitive how to git add a visually selected chunk of code

Tags: visual-mode, git, plugin-fugitive

I would like to know if i could select some code in visual mode and `git add` it ?

I checked with fugitive.vim but i didn't find how to do it.

Is it possible ? Or is there any other plugin to do it ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There might be other ways, but this approach lets you to do more than adding a chunk, which is why I tend to use it quite a lot.

1. Run `:Gdiff` command. It will open a split with version of current file that's currently in the index to the left/top of the original window.
2. While in original window (right or bottom one), perform visual selection of changes you'd like to `git add`.
3. Run `:diffput` command, which can operate on a range. (`dp` key doesn't work in Visual mode.)
4. Close that second window saving changes to update file in the index. Here you can edit it the way you like before saving, it doesn't have to exactly match original or new version of the file.

Mind that `:diffput` might not always give you what you would expect depending on the structure of changes (especially if you're committing only part of contiguous block of changes). So don't forget to validate commit. In most practical situations it works fine though.

Answer (score 49):

**fugitive.vim now allows for staging a selection of a hunk with visual mode.**

1. Open the git summary with `:Git` (or `:G`)
2. Expand the file which contains the lines you want to stage with `>` (or `=` to toggle). This will only show the changed hunks plus some extra lines of context above and below the changed lines.
3. `v` to start visual mode and select the lines you want to stage with `hjkl`
4. `s` to stage the visual selection (or `-` to toggle)
5. Repeat 2-4 as needed
6. `cc` to commit

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @WongJiaHau in the fugitive help files: `:help fugitive-staging-maps`. Or more generally, `:h fugitive`. It's so awesome, it should be illegal ;)

Answer (score 13):

[Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) has a [great series](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/) on [Fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive). The episode [Fugitive.vim - working with the git index](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-working-with-the-git-index/) would be the the most helpful for your question.

You can use `:Gdiff` to stage only portions of a file. Running `:Gdiff` will show you the current file "diff-ed" with the stage/index. You can simply use Vim's diff commands (`dp`, `do`, `:diffput`, and `:diffget`) to move the hunk to the stage/index. Then you write the stage/index file like you would any other buffer, `:w`/`:x`.

Comment: I'm using `:Gstatus` + `D` to do the same with fugitive. This way I can also pick the file I'm operating on among the list of files that have been modified.

Answer (score 13):

#### Stage Complete or Partial Hunks with [`vim-gitgutter`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter)

1. Stage Complete Hunk

   - `<Leader>hs` or
   - `:GitGutterStageHunk`
2. Stage Part of an *Additions-only* Hunk (since 8/2019)

   - Visual mode

     - `{Visual}<Leader>hs`
     - `:'<,'>GitGutterStageHunk`
       (`'<,'>` are as always inserted for you)
   - Range

     - `:42,45GitGutterStageHunk`
3. Stage Part of any Hunk via *Preview Window* (since 8/2019)

   - Preview the hunk, e.g. `<Leader>hp`
   - Move to the preview window, e.g. `:wincmd P`
   - Delete the lines you do not want to stage
   - Stage the remaining lines, e.g. `<Leader>hs` or `:GitGutterStageHunk`

**Updated: 17.8.2019** due to recent commits [bc1d28d](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/commit/bc1d28db46f7d8f174df4b0c98da092e10369281) and [b036fcf](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/commit/b036fcf5274315fbefde53f20bb9b30f19ce80b0)

Comment: It asked for vim-fugitive, not vim-gitgutter

Answer (score 8):

As you specifically asked about solutions that use other plugins, I'll note that you can also stage visual selections using [vimagit](https://github.com/jreybert/vimagit), which is a Git plugin (based on the other editor's popular [Magit plugin](https://github.com/magit/magit)) centered around viewing, staging, and commiting changes.

To stage a visual selection using Vimagit:

1. Run the `:Magit` command to open a new buffer that displays all the changed hunks in your *repository* (not just in one file),
2. Locate the lines you want to stage and perform your `visual` selection,
3. Press the "stage" mapping: `S`.